# Can the walls of a waller elite be broken?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can the walls erected by a "waller" elite monster type be destroyed using attacks or any thing else?

[image: not my image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you can't destroy it. But for example leap allows you to escape. Or I figure teleport could work as well.

NB. "Champions can only create short, straight walls, while Bosses can create three-sided rectangles that box fleeing players in, forcing them to run back past the boss and other monsters to escape."

from [here](http://www.diablowiki.net/Boss_Modifiers#Waller).

Comment: One neat trick is that many Monk abilities work through these walls - Deadly Reach, and Fist of Thunder with Thunderclap will let you strike the enemy on the other side of the wall, even at range, every 3rd strike (or every strike if they're close).

Answer (score 11):

Sure can. At least, they can with this stuff:

[Bottomless Potion of Kulle-Aid](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/bottomless-potion-of-kulleaid)

OH YEAH!

Comment: That's gotta be one of the best references in the game

Comment: Was this added in the ROS expansion?

Comment: yes, also there's a rune for wizards's skill Black Hole - Event Horizon that can remove waller walls.